# Prove that if $y_0 \in \overline{T(kB_X)} \Rightarrow -y_0 \in \overline{T(kB_X)}\quad T\in B(X,Y), k>0$

Tags: real-analysis

My attemp: if $y_0 \in \overline{T(kB_X)} $then exist a succession $\{x_n\}\subseteq kB_X$ so that $Tx_n \rightarrow y_0$ for $n \rightarrow +\infty$.
$T(-x_n)=-T(x_n)$ because T is linear so $T(-x_n) \rightarrow y_0 \in \overline{T(kB_X)}$?

Comment: $T(-x_n) \to -y_0.$ Is your hypothesis true for all $k$ or for some $k?$ What is $k?$ Please write the question with clarity and detail.